# Python check type of none type

Tags: python-3.x

I am doing a loop and setting a variable but I need to know if it is NoneType.

```
get_background = wb.colour_map[bgc]
if isinstance(get_background, None):
    #do stuff
```

Getting `typeerror: isinstance () arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

```
if type(get_background) is 'NoneType':
    #do stuff.
```

This just gets skipped over and my code blows up.
How do I check if `get_background` is of `NoneType`.

```
print(type(get_background))
<class 'Nonetype'>
```

Comment: Try just using `isinstance(get_background, type(None))` or even just `get_background is None`, since None is the only value that can be NoneType.

Comment: Sweetness.  I thought I tried `get_background is None` but clearly I did not.